# LibGDX Assets are not updating

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, build.gradle

I have changed some image files in my assets folder and they are appearing correctly in the Package Explorer of Eclipse but when I run my game the new versions do not appear and the old versions are still being used. When I add a new file and try to use it in code I get a "Couldn't load file" error, even though it is appearing in the file hierarchy. It seems like my assets are stuck as what they were 6 hours ago all of a sudden. What could cause this?

EDIT: The only thing I can think of is that I added new dependencies to the `build.gradle` file, and I think that was around the time new resources stopped loading. Could that be connected?

Comment: Can we see your build.gradle and project structure?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `Project->Clean`, followed by a `Project->Build All`?

Eclipse will most likely not recompile your project automatically, if you do not change the source and just swap out some resources. Thus, your old resource files still reside in the build folder (and in the path at run time). 
Your new files only seem to be present in the source folder and are not used at run time.

Comment: Nothing seems to happen when I select `Build All`, and running the program doesn't change.

Comment: I've edited my question with an idea I had, not sure if that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the bin folder in the project and then rebuilding. This will definitely change it.

The above is not, a permanent fix.